# Unable to run jss build command on build server: 'jss' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Tags: jss

On my TeamCity build server I am attempting to run the `jss build` command in one of the build steps, but it fails with the error:

`'jss' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.`

I know `jss` is properly installed because I can manually run the command from the build directory inside a PowerShell window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JSS Documentation DevOps page](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/devops):

> Tip: when running `jss` CLI commands in an environment where you cannot install global npm packages, you can use `npm run jss [command]` instead, which shims the CLI command through npm. Note that `--` is needed prior to any arguments with npm, e.g. `npm run jss deploy app -- --skipBuild`

If you structure your command as `npm run jss build`, it will work assuming you have the necessary prerequisites (node and the JSS CLI).